# containstable ignores noise word 'of' while searching

Tags: sql, sql-server, containstable, noise-words

I am searching in the DB table with `containstable`. I am searching with text 'center of gravity', but it doesn't return result. If I search with only 'center' or 'gravity', then it returns the result.

How can to overcome this situation?

```
select * from containstable(swInstances, *, '"*Center of gravity*"')
```

Comment: Have you tried `containstable(swInstances, *, '"Center of gravity"')`?

Comment: yeah, I tried that but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem are the positions of the words.  `containstable` is taking into account the position of the stop words, so "center" and "gravity" are not next to each other.  However, "of" is removed from the search term.

Two solutions come to mind.  The first is to use `near` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/search-for-words-close-to-another-word-with-near?view=sql-server-2017#Custom_NEAR)) and allow one stop word of separation.  Of course, this would find "center for gravity" as well.

The second is to eliminate stop words from the search index entirely, so phrases like "center of gravity" can be directly searched.

I'm not sure which is more applicable in your situation.  If I had to guess, `near` might be good enough.